Maximum distance between consecutive terms in sequence with arbitrarily long APs
Good evening. I am writing a paper on complex analysis, and as a corollary (of my work and others'), I believe that I have managed to deduce the following result.
Proposition: Let $n_1 < n_2 \cdots \in \mathbb{N}$ be a set with arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions. Then, for every $\lambda > 1$, there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n_{k+1} < \lambda n_{k}$.
In other words, this gives an (I assume fairly weak) upper bound on the minimum "multiplicative distance" between all consecutive terms for any set with arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.
I played around with this statement a little, testing it with a few examples, and it seemed quite intuitive, but I couldn't see how to prove it directly -- but this isn't saying much as I know very little combinatorics or Fourier analysis at present time.
It would be great to hear from anyone whether or not this result is (1) known to be true (2) trivial (3) known to be false (4) worth including in a paper. (I suppose that (2),(4) and (3),(4) would be as mutually exclusive as (1),(3).) Thank you in advance.

It is (1) and (2): Suppose the contrary and ignore the first few terms. Then if $n$ is the last element of an arithmetic progression, the progression difference is at least $cn$ with $c=1-\lambda^{-1}$, so the progression length is at most $c^{-1}$.

@fedja Very nice. Out it goes, then. It was not the focus of my paper, but now I am interested: there is a small chance that $n_{k+1}/n_k > \lambda$ can be weakened to $n_{k+1}/n_k > 1 + o(1)$. I expect this gives a different answer.

Suppose we have a progression $P = {n_0,n_0+d,\dots,n_0+(k-1)d}$, we have that $\frac{n_0+(k-1)d}{n_0+(k-2)d}\le \frac{(k-1)d}{(k-2)d} = 1+1/(k-2)$. The first inequality is a property of "taking mediants" (if $a/b < c/d$ for positive $a,b,c,d$, then $a/b<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<c/d$).

@ZachHunter Thanks! I was writing up my article, and I thought this might be difficult and thus not worth diverting my time. I really should have thought about it more.
